# Indenting a Paragraph with only Inline CSS

Tags: css, inline-code, text-indent

Going to forego all the background to my problem and just present it:

I need to get CSS to indent paragraphs for me, but I can only use inline CSS. Using the `p {text-indent:15px;}` (or whatever number I need) doesn't work. The text box is basically just BBCode, but I can use inline CSS, provide that I use the BBCode that will enable it. This means I can't have the code at the top (can't remember what this is called), nor can I reference an external style sheet.

When I use just the code for `text-indent:15px;`, it only indents the first line of whatever I've typed, even if there are several breaks in it (hitting enter twice, I mean, like I do here). I don't have the option to keep opening/closing this code (person the code is for can't understand coding at all), and I didn't know if there's a way to do this, or if I should tell them that they're doomed to not indenting their text?

```
[css=background:black; width:500px; margin-left:50px; color:maroon; font-size:12px;][css=padding:5px 25px;]YOUR TEXT SHOULD GO HERE.
[color=white]Your links should be this color.[/color]
[/css][/css]
```

That's what I can write. If I want a link to be a different color than the rest of the text, I have no way to format the links, and I have to use BBCode to change the color every time. By using the `text-indent` property, it'll indent the first line of my text (as it should), and nothing else. Period. Since I'm operating with BBCode and can't use HTML to open/close paragraphs, using the code that operate based off of the paragraph tag (`<p>`) achieves nothing.

Comment: It sounds to me like you don't want 'text-indent', but instead 'padding-left'

Comment: I don't want the whole block of text indented, though, just the first line. Padding-left would move the entire area of text.

Comment: That's a lot of restrictions you have there. Could you provide a more concrete example of the input you're trying to use and what exactly you want it to look like in the end?

Comment: @animuson I changed the first post, with examples of the code I have together so far. I'm sorry if things are still confusing to read, but I'm not too good with words, and it's been a long time since I've had to know terms for coding (not a conversation I have with people who know the terminology, so I use my own, I think).

Answer (score 0):

`p` is a flow element, and `text-indent` exactly indents first line.  Make it a block and use padding:

```
p.yourclass
  { display: inline-block
  ; padding-left: 15px
  }
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, though. With the restrictions of the BBCode that I have to work around, I can _only_ do inline CSS. I've tested doing the code as you've written, but it doesn't work. Only inline CSS will work. If it can't be done, that's fine, but I would like to know before I tell something that I can't do it.

Comment: You can do this CSS inline.

Comment: What stops you from inlining it?
`<p style="padding-left: 15px; display=inline-block">
Lorem ipsum ...</p>` (or whatever syntax BBCode wants)

Comment: Because I can't use HTML in the code, all the text falls under one `<p>` tag. So if they have three paragraphs, only the first one will register with the code and indent with it. Everything else will remain normal. And I don't trust the person everything is being given to, to be able to copy/paste the codes without messing something up.

Comment: You said you can use inline CSS, but now you are saying that you can't.  I don't understand your setup now.